# Issue with spring-boot-starter-jdbc when using in standalone

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-boot, h2

I am trying to use spring-boot-starter-jdbc in a non-web/non-tomcat based scenario.

I tried to exclude tomcat-jdbc so that tomcat doesn't start when i start spring-boot application.

The problem i faced is that

```
spring.datasource.initialize=false
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:52705/~/test
```

Even though i ask spring-boot to not auto-configure a mem db, it always starts one if i dont include tomcat-jdbc. So, there seems to be no way to use spring-boot-starter-jdbc with non-mem h2 database in a standalone kind of application.

Is there a solution to this problem or is it a bug?

Comment: do you have h2 dependency in your pom file?

Comment: yes i have h2 dependency. to prove the whole thing i included tomcat-jdbc, it initiated a different datasource and no embedded db was started.

Comment: have you started the h2 server from your webapp? if not started, any tcp based jdbc url will not work

Answer (score 0):

tomcat-jdbc has nothing to do with the Tomcat server. It is just that Tomcat was looking for a better JDBC connection pool library so they made it and used the tomcat name for the library.

If you want to exclude the web component then you really want to remove the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency on your project as within that there is the dependency on the spring-boot-starter-tomcat.